# Twig function call is removing concatenated variable from the string

Tags: string, symfony, twig

I have a function call that renders an SVG that is just stored in a file. When I add the string explicitly, the function renders the SVG as expected. When I try to use a variable in the path, the Twig function seems to be removing the variable and throwing an Error. Could this be due to some security setting in Twig/PHP?

The example below is referencing the source function, but I am having the same issues with `include`.

```
{% set icn = "@svgs/icons/#{link.icon}.svg" %}
{{ icn }} {# Prints out @svgs/icons/icn-phone.svg #}
{{  source(icn) }} {# Produces an Error: Fatal error : Uncaught  Twig\Error\LoaderError: Unable to find template "@svgs/icons/.svg" #}
{{  source("@svgs/icons/icn-phone.svg") }} {# Works as expected #}
```

You can see in the error it's looking for `@svgs/icons/.svg` and removing the variable.

I've also tried other String Interpolation techniques described [here](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/templates.html#string-interpolation) that produced the same error.

None of these attempts worked either

```
{% include "@svgs/icons/" ~ link.icon ~ ".svg" %}
{{ source("@svgs/icons/%s.svg"|format(link.icon)) }}
{{ source("@svgs/icons/"~link.icon~".svg") }}
```

Thanks in advance.

Full Error

```
Fatal error
: Uncaught Twig\Error\LoaderError: Unable to find template "@svgs/icons/.svg" (looked into: wp-content/themes/xxx). in /var/www/src/templates/nav/dropdown-platform.twig.html:16 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/vendor/twig/twig/src/Loader/FilesystemLoader.php(122): Twig\Loader\FilesystemLoader->findTemplate('@svgs/icons/.sv...') #1 /var/www/vendor/twig/twig/src/Extension/CoreExtension.php(1285): Twig\Loader\FilesystemLoader->getSourceContext('@svgs/icons/.sv...') #2 /var/www/vendor/twig/twig/src/Environment.php(358) : eval()'d code(64): twig_source(Object(Twig\Environment), '@svgs/icons/.sv...') #3 /var/www/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(394): __TwigTemplate_c0bbd02566a8b37f3402a61110ca1a79fd3abdde3641b8500c8bd9e592820079->doDisplay(Array, Array) #4 /var/www/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(367): Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array) #5 /var/www/vendor/twig/twig/src/Environment.php(358) : eval()'d code(161): Twig\Template->display(Array) #6 /var/www/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(394): _ in
/var/www/src/templates/nav/dropdown-platform.twig.html
on line
16
```

Comment: Please verify the contents of `link.icon`, as it stands now it's an empty property. See the error you are getting: `Unable to find template "@svgs/icons/.svg"`, there is no actual filename

Comment: @DarkBee Thanks for the comment. I've verified that value exists by printing out the value of `{{ icn }}`. See the comment here `{{ icn }} {# Prints out @svgs/icons/icn-phone.svg #}`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
{{ source('@svgs/icons/' ~ asset(link.icon ~ '.svg')) }}
```